# Should I use WebView in displaying HTML data?

Tags: android

I have recently started developing my first android app by following The New Boston's ,Level Up Tut's and Vogella.com's tutorial. My goal now is to create an app that will display the contents of this 
[site.](http://desalyearbook.com/featured-plants/al-dur-swro-%E2%80%93-bahrain)

My first plan is to produce a stripped-down version of the articles on that site and then store them in *res/* folder. I will then create a Layout and throw in a WebView and this widget will use the html file.

Second is to store the content in an SQLite database and display it in TextView. My worry if I do this is how to display the images and the styles/formatting of the page, given that TextView seems to have limited support for HTML tags.

So there, I hope you can guide on the proper way to achieve my goal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a static website with no changes to its articles for significant period of time? If that site is optimized for mobile, you can go ahead with the WebView. If not and if you have full access to the resources/articles/images of the site, I would suggest going with the TextView and database way.

Comment: It only has new content on a yearly basis. The site is not optimized for mobile. I do have access to the cms and images so i can probably have it on sqlite. How does one deal with inline images by the way?

Comment: You can save them as a blob in the sqlite db and create a bitmap of appropriate size based on device configuration.